# KVM guest stalls whenever guest disk IO happens

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, kvm

I have a KVM guest I created with virsh. The host machine is Ubuntu 18.04 and the guest machine is Ubuntu 18.04. Both run the `Linux maus 5.3.0-59-generic` kernel and I am using the hardware virtualization provided by the Intel CPU I have. Up until recently this worked fine.

This guest has NICs attached to both my home network and a cable modem. It acts as a NAT device to allow local machines internet access via the cable modem.

I typically run a large number of iptables rules & `tc` commands to improve overall usability of the internet connection. I have the `tc` stuff disabled at present so I am using the default `fq_codel` qdisc provided by ubuntu running only.

I am getting intermittent network stuttering when using the machine as a NAT gateway. Basically a pause in network traffic then everything catches up. Additional troubleshooting confirmed by plugging directly into the cable modem (with my laptop) indicates the internet connection is working fine.

From the host machine, I can ping the guest. Note there is not any sort of virtualized network between my host and my guest. An additional NIC is installed in the physical machine and bridged to the guest. So this has to travel over my local switch. I run the following command: `ping -i 0.22 192.168.12.90` from the host.

Typical latency is less than 1 millisecond. however burst of latency show up

```
4 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=340 ttl=64 time=0.710 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=341 ttl=64 time=0.323 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=342 ttl=64 time=0.234 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=343 ttl=64 time=0.542 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=344 ttl=64 time=0.382 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=345 ttl=64 time=0.253 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=346 ttl=64 time=0.361 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=347 ttl=64 time=0.360 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=348 ttl=64 time=1374 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=349 ttl=64 time=1151 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=350 ttl=64 time=928 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=351 ttl=64 time=704 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=352 ttl=64 time=480 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=353 ttl=64 time=257 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=354 ttl=64 time=34.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=355 ttl=64 time=0.285 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=356 ttl=64 time=0.351 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=357 ttl=64 time=0.400 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.12.90: icmp_seq=358 ttl=64 time=0.341 ms
```

I have also plugged directly into the NIC used by the VM and seen the same behavior, so the issue is not my local switch.

In the host, I ran `stress -c 4 -m 4` to produce as much CPU load as I could. This does not improve or make the problem worse.

I eventually noticed that `journald` is usually doing some brief IO when the stutter happens. In the guest I ran something like this: `dd if=/dev/zero of=./fstest bs=4096 count=25000`. This causes the stuttering problem to happen immediately. So obviously, I've established that disk IO in the guest causes the problem.

Running the same `dd` command in the host does not cause the problem. This makes me think that *somehow* the guest has gotten into a bad state.

This is the entirety of my very simple disk configuration

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
      <source dev='/dev/corona/gateway_ii'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
```

The device `/dev/corona/gateway_ii` is a device created using LVM in the host

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/corona/gateway_ii
  LV Name                gateway_ii
  VG Name                corona
  LV UUID                xlpkI2-3qW1-7Jld-N30q-Vl05-nR9I-8jgijJ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time maus, 2020-03-29 18:31:31 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                30.00 GiB
  Current LE             7680
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:9
```

I bumped up the VM to having two CPUs allocated, but it makes absolutely no difference

So my questions are

1. What could be happening where disk write seems to basically flatline the guest VM?
2. Where should I go next for troubleshooting?

Comment: When you compared the `dd` commands between the host and guest, did you do this on LVs in the same VG? When you ran `dd` within the guest the "I/O stack" was something like filesystem -> virtio -> mirrored LV (device mapper) -> disk. What about when running `dd` on the host?